# .htaccess with multiple requirements

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My `.htaccess` file needs to provide the following:

- Forced HTTPS
- Forced WWW
- Remove PHP file extension
- Trailing slash (optional)
- Force particulars.php?id=XXX to particulars/XXX (with trailing slash if used)
- Force properties.php?location=1&rooms=2&rent=3&sort=4 to properties/1/2/3/4 (with trailing slash if used)

The closest I have managed to come (which covers forced WWW, removing PHP file extension and adding the trailing slash) is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force WWW prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]

# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

But I have been unable to customise this to cover everything above. I have tried multiple combinations of the `.htaccess` rules out there to no avail, so are there any `.htaccess` experts out there willing to help? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `Force WWW prefix` block you can have these additional rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(properties)\.php\?location=([^\s&]+)&rooms=([^\s&]+)&rent=([^\s&]+)&sort=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(properties)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?location=$2&rooms=$3&rent=$4&sort=$5 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(properties)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(properties)/([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

**Edit:** To **force HTTPS** change `# Force WWW prefix` rule to this:

```
# Force WWW prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Chang `www.domain.com` to your actual domain.

Comment: Thank you! If you could update this to include a rule to force to HTTPS I'd be happy to accept this as the answer =)

Comment: ok see edit part for that and remember it replaces your existing `www` 301 rule.

Comment: Super - much appreciated!